# Prevent Overriding bean definition for bean

Tags: java, spring

I know we can disable the overloading of spring beans through:

```
GenericApplicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(boolean b)
```

[Spring Ref](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding%28boolean%29)

However, I consider a WebApplicationContext not loaded programatically, but through my web.xml file. Then, how can I prevent the overring of Spring bean in a WebApplicationContext

Comment: Use a Servlet ContextListener and get a reference to the context and then call the method above.

Answer (score 4):

One, not particularily elegant way would be to override default WebApplicationContext. In web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>my.package.MyWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

where

```
public class MyWebApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext {
  public MyWebApplicationContext() {
    super();
    this.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
  }
}
```